# How to detect an empty div, then insert a html button with either JS or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1. List item

I have a page with divs that are fed by API
Sometimes the API returns no data
so If it returns no data (detect empty div) and insert a html button instead

```
    <div id="delivery_result"></div>


    <div class="empty-state"><button id='update_subscription' class="btn-fix-subscription">There seems to be a issue with your payment method Please Click Here To Fix</button></div>


    <script>

    if ($('#delivery_result').contents().length == 0) {

        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("div#delivery_result").append("<button id='update_subscription' class="btn-fix-subscription">There seems to be a issue with your payment method Please Click Here To Fix</button>}); 

      }

    </script>
```

I also have the hidden div .empty-state and was trying to use css to unhide it just was not working, so i am trying JS but dont know crap about JS i dont care which way as long as if the #delivery_result div is empty (no data form api) then it will display the button that takes them to correct payment and then the api feeds data

My above code does not work it shows the button regardless if div is empty or not

So to summarize:
1. Detect if div ID delivery_result is empty and if so unhide .empty-state so button will show
2. Maybe `#delivery_result:empty` ? but I couldn't get it to work couldn't figure out how to go from there to unhide the hidden div

This didn't work but would be the perfect solution sure I'm just mucking something up with the code in either case pleas help :)

```
div.eq:empty ~ .empty-state {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: #ec3d10;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:1300;
}

.empty-state {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: document ready inside of the if make little sense. What is the api? Ajax or backend sets it when page renders.

Comment: You'd be better off putting the logic where you get the data, then it's simply a case of *if there's data then display it, else display something else*

Comment: its ajax called to the recharge api

Answer (score 4):

In it's simplest form, something like this?

```js
function addButton() {
 let button = `<button>Click Here</button>`;
 $( "div:empty" )
   .append(button);
}

addButton();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Has Content -->
<div>I've got content</div>
<div>I've got content</div>
<div>I've got content</div>

<!-- Not Content -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: `(function(){
  let btn = '<button>Click Here</button>'
  $('div:empty').append(btn)
})()`

Comment: how do i restrict this just to the div with the ID #delivery_schedule as it stands it applies it to all empty divs

Comment: you would just replace `'div:empty'` with `'#delivery_schedule:empty'`

Comment: seems to be placing the button when there is data as well as without data

Comment: hmm... can you create https://codepen/pen and include the link here with your code? I'll help you get it to where you're wanting it to be

Comment: https://codepen.io/rpandassociates/pen/WLoVgx thanks i just can get it to go not sure why it detects it as empty after the api fed data

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript part should be like this one:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($.trim($('#delivery_result').html()) == '') {
            $("div#delivery_result").append('<button id="update_subscription" class="btn - fix - subscription">There seems to be a issue with your payment method Please Click Here To Fix</button>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: not sure who marked it down wasnt me Im here for a solution ill try anything :) this solution still displayed the button even though the api fed data

Comment: Try it now i added the combination of $.trim() with .html() and is working on my local env

Comment: The function should be on the success callback of your ajax call, not on the ready

Comment: i just upvoted your answer..i can't stand people downvoting w/ out an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are consistent with how you use your quotation marks.

Part of the reason your code is broken due to not escaping quotes properly.

[EDIT] So that you don't need to create the HTML inside the JavaScript, the code will copy the HTML from the hidden element (now with id "empty-state-element").

```
<div id="delivery_result"></div>

<div id="empty-state-element" class="empty-state" style="display:none;">
    <button id="update_subscription" class="btn-fix-subscription">
        There seems to be a issue with your payment method Please Click Here To Fix
    </button>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myDiv = $('#delivery_result');
        if (myDiv.is(':empty')) {
            myDiv.append($('#empty-state-element').html());
        }
    }); 

</script>
```